# Is there any way to squash commits with uncommitted changes?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I want to squash two commits.

I'm executing the following command:

```
hg rebase --dest .~2 --base . --collapse
```

Which gives me:

```
abort: uncommitted changes
```

Yes, I have uncommitted changes and I want to keep them.
Is there any way to force this?

Answer (score 1):

You can shelve the uncommitted changes and then do the rebase. Once you are done, unshelve the changes.

```
hg shelve

hg rebase ...

hg unshelve
```

I highly recommend backing up your repository first, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: This is a good approach. Curious about the recommendation to backup first, however? Are you thinking, in case the rebase goes wrong?

Comment: Yes, I have had that happen. Also have had the shelved changes become orphaned.

Comment: I've also messed up a rebase and had no way to go back on it. Sometimes I merge instead of rebase whenever I'm a little uncertain of the outcome.

Comment: Time has taught me to be paranoid. Mercurial is by far the most robust and usable revision control system that I have used. It almost never has issues, but it is always good to have a backup just in case.